# Why does the jQuery mouseenter even not work on first try, but works on second?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

For my dropdown, and other dropdowns I've made recently, the jQuery mouseenter event doen't fire on the initial mouseenter. On the second mouseenter attempt without loading the page, it does fire.

Partial Fix: When I remove `display: none` from the child element in the CSS, and I assign:

```
$(SELECTOR).css({'display' : 'none'})
```

to the child using jQuery, then everything works correctly. But this is a bad approach because `display: none` should be set in the CSS. Due to this method, which I refer to as my partial fix, if JS is turned off then the subnav will always show.

In addition, my jQuery seems to work fairly well in Firefox, and not at all in Chrome.

Here is the latest JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xd645/2/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly in chrome!

Comment: working in chrome and firefox

Comment: Could it be that you're mousing over before the document is ready?

Comment: Works fine here in Chrome. Are you suffering from cached CSS? CTRL-F5 your Chrome to see.

Comment: For me, the initial mouseenter is not firing. It is the CSS version that is firing initially. So you won't see `slideDown()`. The second time you hover you'll see the `slideDown()` fire. I'm using the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, and experiencing this issue in both. A couple of my colleagues are seeing the same problem. As for the JSFiddle, it is inside $(document).ready();

Comment: @ScriptsConnect Event is firing first time here, could it be some sort of caching error or glitch on your end ?

Comment: In addition, Chrome doesn't appear to be working. AlexAr, are you sure the fiddle is working in Chrome? The only way I can get it to work is to change `.on('mouseenter', function(){` to `.hover(function(){`

Comment: Its working here in chrome too...